# Integrating an Algolia InstantSearch Vue Component into a Vuetify Data-table

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, algolia

I am building a **Vue JS** Application, with a **Vuetify data-table**, and an **Algolia InstantSearch Vue Component** into it. However currently the data-table, and the InstantSearch index are using different data sources.

How should I integrate the search results from the Algolia index into the Vuetify data-table?

```
 <div id="App">
        <v-app id="inspire" v-cloak>
            <ais-index app-id="{{ config('scout.algolia.id') }}" index-name="{{ (new App\FoodCat)->searchableAs() }}"
               api-key="{{ Algolia\ScoutExtended\Facades\Algolia::searchKey(App\FoodCat::class) }}">

                <section id="widget-grid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 sortable-grid ui-sortable">
                            <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-sortable" id="wid-id-2" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false">
                                <header class="ui-sortable-handle">
                                    <div class="widget-header">
                                        <h2><i class="fa fa-list text-orange"></i> Food Categories List</h2>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="widget-toolbar smart-form">
                                        <label class="input">
                                            <i class="icon-append fa fa-search"></i>
                                            <ais-input placeholder="Search By Keyword"></ais-input>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="widget-toolbar smart-form">
                                        <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
                                            <input v-model="form.inputs.title.val" type="text" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.title }" name="title" value="" :placeholder="(form.errors.title) ? 'Category Title Required' : 'Add Food Category'" />
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <button class="btn btn-sm text-white bg-orange widget-hdr-btn" v-html="form.btnText" @click.prevent="(formMode == 'add') ? add() : save()"></button>

                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger widget-hdr-btn" @click="deleteSelected"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete Selected</button>
                                </header>

                                <!-- widget div-->
                                <div role="content" class="widget-content no-padding">
                                    <!-- widget content -->
                                    <div class="widget-body">
                                        <ais-results>
                                           <template scope="{ result }">
                                               <div>
                                                   <h1>@{{ result.title }}</h1>
                                                   <h4>@{{ result.slug }}</h4>
                                               </div>
                                           </template>
                                        </ais-results>

                                        <v-progress-linear :indeterminate="true" :height="3" color="#c79121" :active="loadingVal"></v-progress-linear>
                                        <v-data-table v-model="selected" :headers="headers" :items="collection" :pagination.sync="pagination" select-all item-key="id" class="elevation-1" >
                                            <template v-slot:headers="props">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th><v-checkbox :input-value="props.all" color="#c79121" :indeterminate="props.indeterminate" primary hide-details @click.stop="toggleAllSelected"></v-checkbox></th>
                                                    <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text"
                                                        :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '']"
                                                        @click="changeSort(header.value)">
                                                        <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
                                                        @{{ header.text }}
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </template>

                                            <template v-slot:items="props">
                                                <tr :active="props.selected" @click="props.selected = !props.selected">
                                                    <td class="text-center align-middle">
                                                        <v-checkbox :input-value="props.selected" primary hide-details color="#c79121"></v-checkbox>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="text-center align-middle">@{{ props.item.id }}</td>
                                                    <td>@{{ props.item.title }}</td>
                                                    <td>@{{ props.item.slug }}</td>
                                                    <td class="text-right align-middle">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="edit(props.item.id)"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Edit Food Category</button>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="remove(props.item.id)"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete Food Category</button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </template>
                                            <template slot="no-data">
                                                <p class="text-xs-center">No Data</p>
                                            </template>
                                        </v-data-table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </ais-index>
        </v-app>
    </div>
```

---

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#App',
    mixins: [ crudFunctionsMixin ],
    data: () => ({
        model: "food-cat",
        modelName: "Food Category",
        modelNamePlural: "Food Categories",
        form: {
            inputs: {
                id:     { val: '', save: true },
                title:  { val: '', save: true, add: true },
                slug:   { val: '', save: true, add: true },
            },
            btnText: "<i class='fa fa-plus-square-o'></i> Add Food Category",
            errors: false
        },
        formSearch: {
            inputs: {
                keywords:   ''
            }
        },
        headers: [
            { text: 'ID', value: 'id', sortable: true },
            { text: 'Title', value: 'title', sortable: true },
            { text: 'Slug', value: 'slug', sortable: true },
            { sortable: false }
        ],
        pagination: {
            sortBy: 'title'
        },
        collection: []
    }),
    watch: {

    },
    methods: {
        fetch() {
            $.get(`/${this.model}/fetch`, (r) => {
                if(r.successMsg) {
                    this.collection = r.collection;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
app.fetch();
```

Comment: Did you managed to fix your issue?

Comment: No  didn't get it to work yet.

Comment: I can clearly see the code you say is "not working", but what isn't working about it? Be more specific man